# Is my network vulnerable due to an exposed minecraft port?

Tags: ip, port, minecraft, ddos

I have setup a small minecraft server and want it to be able to be accessed over the internet. I originally wanted to set up a reverse proxy in order to hide my IP but found out that this is not possible for a minecraft server, which means that my real IP is going to be exposed.

Will my network be vulnerable to DoS attacks if I expose a single port to access the server and use the minecraft's built in whitelist?

This would of course mean that only white-listed accounts can join the server, but I am wondering if this could still pose a threat to the network since all requests would still need to pass through the modem/router. (On which my ISP does not let me manage my own firewall rules).

(I do not intend to publicly advertise the IP and will only share it with friend and family, however I'd rather be safe than sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, if you have a port open you are always vulnerable to DoS! Technically on the Internet you are always vulnerable, even without having a port open... But I guess in your case the risk is minimal, since no one should have an interest to use extensive resources just to DoS some random minecraft server... for hosting games, I have ports open since years and they are even public! but nothing ever happened, because no one cares!